# Using GithHubAction with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using GitHub Actions to deploy my code using Terraform. Whenever code is pushed to the `Testing` branch, a GitHub Action is triggered that builds the code and runs `terraform apply` . This works well.

The problem is that now I want to have a `Prod` environment too. Whenever code is pushed to the `Prod` branch, it should be built using its own s3 remote backend and its AWS account. The problem I'm having is that I am not sure how to configure my terraform files so that terraform GitHubAction can use the backend for Prod to store the state file.please anyone who is able to help.Im not sure at this point how to set that up. here is the sample of my code

```
name: "Terraform-Apply-Action"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - prod

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
      AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: Init
        run: terraform init

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: terraform plan -no-color
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Terraform Plan Status
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'failure'
        run: exit 1

      - name: Terraform Apply
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Answer (score 0):

The s3 backend key for terraform needs to be different across branches if you are doing it like that.

Testing:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "testing/path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Prod:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "prod/path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

There are numerous other ways to solve this - but this is a very quick and easy solution.